# App File Size is 2.5x larger when installing with Fabric

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter-fabric

I am trying to figure out why my apps file size is so large when I install a beta build with Fabric Beta (created by Twitter).

When archiving the build and checking the app size I see that it is about 194MB, however, when I build and install the app for debugging on device, the storage space that is taken up is ~85MB.

When I install the app via Fabric Beta, the app is ~194MB on device.

Would anyone be able to explain what is going on here. Is there an issue with Fabric that is not optimizing the build?

Comment: Most likely the ipa for uploading has arm6 and arm7 binaries in it.  As long as you have bitcode turned on then App thinning will only push down the parts that an individual device needs.

Comment: I see. And is there any way to confirm this for a client? Because Fabric has been the only platform we have been using. Will I see the correct file size with iTunes Test Flight?

Comment: Well an IPA is just a zip file.   You can rename it and unzip it and see what's taking up space inside it.

Comment: I see the IPA file is 40MB

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but worth clarifying I think real quick:

1 comment said:

> Most likely the ipa for uploading has arm6 and arm7 binaries in it. As long as you have bitcode turned on then App thinning will only push down the parts that an individual device needs.

And this is true, and then this follow up comment from original question author

> I see. And is there any way to confirm this for a client? Because Fabric has been the only platform we have been using. Will I see the correct file size with iTunes Test Flight?

The answer to that is yes. Test flight, since basically the closest you can get to the App Store without actually getting reviewed (although TestFlight requires Beta App Review, but this is usually pretty quick.

TestFlight should handle the proper app thinning and send you only the app binary sized for your device.